Why is Lucas 22:35 using "quando" and not "cum"?
In Vulgate Lucas 22:35:

Quando misi vos sine sacculo, et pera, et calceamentis, numquid aliquid defuit vobis?

As far as I know, the rule for translating "when" into Latin is that you use "quando" when "when" is an adverb ("When will you return?"), but that you use "cum" when "when" is a conjuction ("When I return, I will..."). But, in this context, "when" is clearly a conjunction, so why did Jerome use "quando"?

Where did you learn that rule from? I'm afraid it's not true.

@JoonasIlmavirta I don't remember whether I read it in Hereditas Linguae Latinae or in Elementa Latina, but I am quite sure it's from one of those two textbooks.

Surprising, because it is indeed wrong. Quando is also a conjunction, as e.g. L&S will tell you.

I believe (just by heart) there is some correlation, at least in Ecclesiastical Latin/the VG, but maybe it's not a hard rule. And maybe the criterion is somewhat more elaborate: what time/that time --> quando; at the same time --> cum.

@Rafael What do you mean by "just by heart"?

I mean, by hearing, by intuition, by experience, as opposed to anything I can easily cite or prove...
